# Character String Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

For part of a homework assignment I need to loop a prompt that has the user enters words until they either enter 20 words or until they enter the word 'done'. Currently, I have both parameters satisfied, but when if I enter the word 'done', it gets scanned into the array as well, which is not what I want to do.

This is my current function:

```
int row = 0;
int column = 0;
int i = 0;

while(i < 20)
    {
      printf("Enter words you would like hidden in the puzzle. Type 'done' when finished:\n");
      scanf("%s",a[i]);

      if(strcmp(a[i],"done") == 0)
      {
        break;
      }

      if((strlen(a[i]) > row) || (strlen(a[i]) > col))
      {
        printf("Error. Word was too long to enter into puzzle.\n");
      }

      else
      {
        i++;
      }
    }
```

The array 'a' is an array of character strings. I know that the line `scanf("%s",a[i]);` is scanning the word 'done' into the array, I just don't know how to tweak it so that doesn't happen.
Can someone please help me figure this part out?

Comment: What do you think the `scanf("%s",a[i]);` line is doing?

Comment: What is "a".  An array of ?

Comment: You could do a `i--;` in your "done" `if`. Or you could do `a[i] = NULL` depending on the type of `a` and what you're doing after this `while`.

Comment: Or you could read the name into a spare string (`char data[32];` or whatever) and if it is not `done`, copy it into the target array — `a` in your code.  But simply decrementing the count is simpler.

Comment: @Bidu - if `a[i]` is an array, that won't work. If it's a pointer then it should be pointing to dynamically allocated memory, so that would be a memory leak.

Comment: Really need to show declaration of `a`.

Comment: How he used it suggests that it's an array of pointers so setting one of his cell to NULL is valid. And I've pointed that it depends on the type of `a` in my first comment.

Comment: It's "valid" in that it's not a compilation error, but it would cause a memory leak

Comment: Ok, I see, do a `free()` before. Anyway decrementing the counter is simpler and better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
char input[256];
while(i < 20)
{
  printf("Enter words you would like hidden in the puzzle. Type 'done' when finished:\n");
  scanf("%s",&input);
  if(strcmp(input,"done") != 0)
  {
    strcpy(a[i],input);
    if((strlen(a[i]) > row) || (strlen(a[i]) > col))
    {
      printf("Error. Word was too long to enter into puzzle.\n");
    }
    i++;
  }
  else
    break;
}
```

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Used to be a c# programmer. :-) Anyway, edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I think you might need an `strcpy` instead of `a[i] = input`. Also, I think `scanf("%s",input);` not `scanf("%s",&input);`.